# Async issue with Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm running into an async issue I hope I can get help in. The error I'm getting is

```
index.js:2178 Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in CreateRoomPage (created by Route)
```

The location of this error is within this function. The two location are found where it says loginPromise.then and the setState which is at the bottom of the function. I'm currently calling this function when a person clicks on .

```
  createUser(e) {
    if (this.state.username === "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({
        errors: "Username can't be blank"
      });

      return;
    }

    const loginPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          window.user = user;
          resolve(user.uid);
        } else {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .signInAnonymously()
            .then(user => {
              resolve(user.uid);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        }
      });
    });
    loginPromise.then(id => {
      let db = firebase.database();
      let playersRef = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}/players`);
      playersRef.child(`${id}`).set(`${this.state.username}`);
      let player = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}/players/${id}`);
      player.onDisconnect().remove();

      let allPlayers = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}/all-players`);
      allPlayers.child(`${id}`).set(true);
      let allPlayer = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}/all-players/${id}`);
      allPlayer.onDisconnect().remove();

      let scoreBoard = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}/scoreBoard`);
      scoreBoard.child(`${this.state.username}`).set(0);
      let playerScore = db.ref(
        `Room/${this.state.roomId}/scoreBoard/${this.state.username}`
      );
      playerScore.onDisconnect().remove();

      let creator = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}`);
      creator.child("creator").set(`${id}`);

      db.ref(`Room/${this.state.roomId}`)
        .child("gameStarted")
        .set(false);

      this.setState({
        username: "",
        errors: ""
      });
    });
```

I've spend nearly 3 hours trying to figure this out. I'm hoping someone can teach me where I'm making this error. I've tried to use a local state where once the componentDidMount it'll change local state to true and back to false once it unmounted like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isMounted: true }, () => {
      if (this.state.isMounted) {
        let db = firebase.database();
        let roomRefKey = db.ref("Room").push().key;
        this.setState({
          roomId: roomRefKey
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Below is another place where it throws such an error

```
createUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      this.state.username.length === 0 &&
      this.state.accesscode.length === 0
    ) {
      this.setState({
        errors: {
          username: "Username can't be blank",
          accesscode: "Access Code can't be blank"
        }
      });
      return;
    }

    if (this.state.username.length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        errors: { username: "Username can't be blank", accesscode: "" }
      });
      return;
    }

    if (this.state.accesscode.length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        errors: { username: "", accesscode: "Access Code can't be blank" }
      });
      return;
    }

    const loginPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          window.user = user;
          resolve(user.uid);
        } else {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .signInAnonymously()
            .then(user => {
              resolve(user.uid);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        }
      });
    });
    loginPromise.then(id => {
      let db = firebase.database();
      let playersRef = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/players`);
      playersRef.child(`${id}`).set(`${this.state.username}`);
      let player = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/players/${id}`);
      player.onDisconnect().remove();

      let allPlayers = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/all-players`);
      allPlayers.child(`${id}`).set(true);
      let allPlayer = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/all-players/${id}`);
      allPlayer.onDisconnect().remove();

      let scoreBoard = db.ref(`Room/${this.state.accesscode}/scoreBoard`);
      scoreBoard.child(`${this.state.username}`).set(0);
      let playerScore = db.ref(
        `Room/${this.state.accesscode}/scoreBoard/${this.state.username}`
      );
      playerScore.onDisconnect().remove();

      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: `/waiting-room/${this.state.accesscode}`
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I would bet that the button that you are clicking is reloading the page and thus causing the setState to fail. Try putting the `e.preventDefault()` at the top of your `createUser` function

Comment: @Jackson Truly amazing. Love to be learning something new. Thank you! took your advice and it helped resolve the issue in two places.

Comment: @Jackson I got a question. It worked in the createPage but in the waitingPage the e.preventDefault() isn't working. I've added the section where it fails. Do you see why e.preventDefault isn't working?